# Calculate distance matrix in km units not degrees

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, mapping, vertices, distance-matrix

I need to calculate the distance of England crimes to the Uk coast. I have a shapefile of the outline of the coast and extracted the vertices. So then I can input the crimes to the coast in distance matrix. However, it keeps giving the  results in degrees. What am I doing wrong? My CRS is EPSG:27700. I don't know how to get UTM zone for England?

[image]

Comment: If this were degree, your definition of England would include the whole Earth, the Moon and all of Space 7 times as far as the moon is. Have you measured the distance of one or two points manually to check your results? Can you provide more details on your data, its CRS, and your exact workflow?

Comment: those are almost certainly in metres so I would divide by 1000 to get Km.